# Is casting to nullable type a bad idea?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have always gone by the idea that casting should be avoided at all costs.  Of course, there are times you have no real choice (particularly when you need to cast between interface types when multiple interfaces are supported).

One pattern i've seen myself using a lot lately is casting from a non-nullable type to nullable type.  For example:

```
public int? GetFooBar(someCriteria) {
    // Code to get a Foo
    return foo == null ? null : (int?)foo.Bar; // Bar is a non-null int
}
```

Is they cast my only choice here?  What other options might I have?

I suppose i could just throw an exception, but I don't like litering my code with exception handlers that aren't necessary.  Plus, not finding a foo might be an expected occurance, and not considered "exceptional".

Comment: I usually prefer casting the `null` just in case, since there's never a harm in that.

Comment: Also you can define default value for bar as static member.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - Can you explain that in more detail?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: It's not good idea (but another choice:), but if you allowed to have default value: `return foo == null?Foo.DefaultBar:foo.Bar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always:

```
if(foo == null)
    return null;

return foo.Bar;
```

No casting involved and a little clearer, at the expense of conciseness.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think this is the right way to do it.  Conciseness be damned.

Comment: That actually feels _more_ concise to me. I don't just measure conciseness by character count--in this case, it's the amount of time it takes for the characters to all make it into my brain.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just point out that

```
return foo == null ? null : (int?)foo.Bar;
```

compiles to the same opcodes as

```
return foo == null ? new Nullable<int>() : new Nullable<int>(foo.Bar);
```

The version with an if statement might also compile to the same opcodes, so it's really just a matter of personal taste. How about this version:

```
return foo == null ? (int?)null : foo.Bar;
```

Same thing. You have to point out the nullable part in either the second or third operand of the conditional operator if you want to use it.